# EF Core: The name "SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy" does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I just updated my project to ASP .NET Core 2.1 and when I run:

```
migrations add InitialCreate
```

It creates a migrations folder, but I get this error and my project won't build:

> The name "SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy" does not exist in the
>   current context.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

[`SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.sqlservervaluegenerationstrategy) is defined into `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll` in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata`.

Make sure you installed the following Nuget package [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent of this for MySql?

Comment: It's a guess, but this looks pretty close @Rez.Net  https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/

Comment: Solved it for me, still works

Answer (score 5):

In the case of [.NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/get-started/install/#net-core-cli):

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```